# Upload file with Django Views

Tags: python, django

I am working on a feature for a Django application that uploads files (images in my context) to the server. Everything is working fine but I am wondering how I can receive as callback the uploaded file path.

Here is my View:

```
def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['uploadedFile'])
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form})
```

My Form:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    uploadedFile = forms.FileField()
```

And my handler:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(source):
    fd, filepath = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix=source.name, dir=FILE_UPLOAD_DIR)
    with open(filepath, 'wb') as dest:
        shutil.copyfileobj(source, dest)
    return filepath
```

I know that `handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['uploadedFile'])` from my view is the required string that I need as callback but how to receive it in the response? 
It is possible to receive instead of my index.html (it is there just for testing purposes) the path of the image for further manipulation in the frontend part. 
I might sound like a noob but I really want if that works somehow. 
Also is there a way for my View to handle multiple file upload? It is something that I need to change in my handler? 
Sorry for putting so many questions...

Comment: file_path = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['uploadedFile'])

Comment: I know that I need to define a variable that store the file path but how I include it in the response? It works like that for example: `return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form}, file_path)`

Comment: Inside the dictionary: `return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form, 'file_path': file_path})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file_path = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['uploadedFile']) 
return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form, 'file_path': file_path})
```

Comment: Based on your answer, thank you very much by the way for the guidance, I come up with this: `file_path = upload_handler(request.FILES['uploadedFile'])` `return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'paths': file_path}), content_type="application/json")` Now I don't need a template anymore :D but based on my code from above what is the best approach so that my view to handle multiple files? A for loop perhaps?